# Mysql select UNIQUE row on column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table as following:(Ex)

```
id   | vid | time
------------------------
1    |  4  | 1333635317
2    |  4  | 1333635323
3    |  2  | 1333635336
4    |  4  | 1333635343
5    |  5  | 1333635349
```

I want to be just a row (the last row [ID: 4]) of the same rows`[id:1,2,4]`, how it will output the query?

I mean, as a result of these:

```
id   | vid | time
------------------------
3    |  2  | 1333635336
4    |  4  | 1333635343
5    |  5  | 1333635349
```

What do i do?

i trying it as:

```
SELECT * from tbale as t1 where vid = 4 GROUP BY vid ORDER BY id DESC
```

but doesn't work `ORDER BY` in my query.

Answer (score 1):

Get the `max` time per vid and use `in` to get those rows from the table.

```
select * from tablename
where (vid,time) in (select vid,max(time) 
                     from tablename 
                     group by vid)
order by id
```